# Show that the measure $\mu ([a,b]) = \ln \left( \frac{1+b}{1+a} \right)$ is invariant for function $\Phi_k$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

A measure is defined as:

$\mu ([a,b]) = \int_a^b \frac{1}{1+x} = ln \left( \frac{1+b}{1+a} \right)$

The function $\Phi_k$ is defined as:

- $\Phi_k = kx$ for: $x \in \left(0, \frac{1}{k} \right)$
- $\Phi_k = \{ \frac{1}{x} \} = \frac{1}{x} \mod 1 $ for: $x \in \left( \frac{1}{k}, 1 \right)$

Show that the measure $\mu(x)$ is invariant for $\Phi_k$.

By invariant I mean that: for every $[a,b]$ it is true that: $\mu (\Phi_k^{-1}([a,b])) = \mu([a,b])$

---

I found a simpler, similar example, explained right here: https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/Charles.Walkden/ergodic-theory/lecture14.pdf

I know that function $\Phi_k$ looks like that:
[image]

In the pink points the graphs (blue, green, purple, black) get cut and the rest of $\Phi_k$ is exchanged for the red part.

I was unable to emulate the thinking form the link into my case. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to take mod 1 when $x\in (1/k,1)$.

Comment: I assume your measure is defined on $(0,1)$, right? Also, by invariant you mean $\mu(\Phi_k([a,b])=\mu([a,b])$, am I right?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your interest. I will modify my initial question to make it more clear.

Comment: As far as I understand, invariant means that: for every $[a,b]$ it is true that: $\mu (\Phi_k^{-1}([a,b])) = \mu([a,b])$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to show that

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \varphi(\Phi_k(x)) \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x) = \int_{0}^{1} \varphi(x) \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x) $$

for all test functions $\varphi \in C([0,1])$. However,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \varphi(\Phi_k(x)) \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x)
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{k}} \varphi(kx) \, \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x} + \int_{\frac{1}{k}}^{1} \varphi(\{1/x\}) \, \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x} \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \varphi(x) \, \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{k+x} + \int_{1}^{k} \varphi(\{x\}) \, \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x(x+1)} \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \varphi(x) \, \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{k+x} + \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \int_{0}^{1} \varphi(x) \, \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(x+j)(x+j+1)} \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \varphi(x) \biggl( \frac{1}{k+x} + \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{(x+j)(x+j+1)} \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \varphi(x) \cdot \frac{1}{1+x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \varphi(x) \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x).
\end{align*}

Therefore the desired conclusion follows.